# BizTalk - Is there a way to get the input file name (received file name) via SQL query in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a requirement to get the suspended messages with the input file details.

I have managed to get the suspended messages using sql query. however, I am unable to get the input file details (received file). Is there a way to get the input file details using SQL query?

Tried to query the input file (received file) details. But could not find the table details in db.

Version : BizTalk 2013

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, Sorry it's a typo.. corrected now. Thanks

Comment: There are PowerShell scripts like https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1062097/Monitor-BizTalk-ports-suspended-messages-and-send that will list suspended messages, but I can't recall if any of them show the filename, which I take it you are after.

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf for the update. I am able to get the suspended messages. But the requirement is to get the filename. Its not available in the given portal.

Comment: The other options is to have an Orchestration that subscribes to failed messages, and then it can access to context properties and get the filename, and either send an email, save the payload (with the original file name), or other actions.